# Boost named conditional variables and notify

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mutex

So I am using the Boost library to make a thread wait until another threads function is finished

Thread 1

```
ipc::named_condition cdv_Android_socket( ipc::open_or_create, "cdv_Android_socket" );

cdv_Android_socket.wait(lock);
```

This waits until a function in a DLL runs this

Thread 2

```
ipc::named_condition cdv_Android_socket( ipc::open_or_create, "cdv_Android_socket" );
cdv_Android_socket.notify_one();
```

The problem Im having is that `notify_one()` is being called before the `wait` statement. I have seen other examples where a `bool` was used to remember the state of `notify`. I can't do this however because there no variables are shared between my main thread and the DLL thread.

Comment: why are you using `ipc::named_condition` instead of [`boost::condition_variable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable)?